# Repetedly call a function

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, nstimer

I am creating a function which is going to be called after every 5 mins , untill the project is deleted from the background.

I have implemented the NSTimer , but it creates issue Like crash and being some what difficult to manage,

Is there any way to call a function repeatedly without using timer after every 5 mins ?

One approach I found is to use Alarm services but I don't know the way to implement.

Edit: Sample one

if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"IsUpdateConfigON"] == TRUE){

```
        //NSLog(@"*****************   One Timer to call UpdateConfig");

    NSString *updatedDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"IsUpdateConfigLastUpdateTime"];    
    int time = [Global getTimeDiff:updatedDate];

        //NSLog(@"********************************** Timer value UPDATE CONGIF  %d",time);


    if(time >= 10){     

            //NSLog(@"****************** When time : %d >=  %d  :Config_Interval seconds ",time,Config_Interval);
        cls_ConfigurationJSON *objConfig = [[cls_ConfigurationJSON alloc]init];
        [objConfig loadView];
        [objConfig release];
    }
}
```

Where time is the count down of time , 1 , 2, 3 etc. This function is called after every 5 minites.

So if any one has any suggestion or code please help me.

Comment: how `NSTimer` is hard to manage? Post some code of your crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSTimer` is the preferred way to call methods frequently. The crash that occurs might be due to issues related to release of objects or invalidation of timer etc.

Comment: Hey 7KV7 thanks for the answer , So except NSTimer there is no any Better option available for now , am I correct ?

Comment: Yes its probably the ideal one.

Answer (score 1):

NSTimer is really a good option when you want to call some function after certain duration. If  you can post you code we will try to resolve your crash problems.

Other possible option in threading is to make an infinite loop and put wait statement.

You can call the function with infinite loop from this.

`[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:<#(SEL)selector#> toTarget:<#(id)target#> withObject:<#(id)argument#>]`

and after performing operation you can make it sleeping for 5 minute using this.

`[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:<#(NSTimeInterval)ti#>]`

Finally make sure that once your application goes into background no process can run longer than 10 min. So I will not be possible to run some process till it is deleted from back ground.

Answer (score 1):

nstimer is the best option as it runs in a separate thread... this is what i have used in my code and causes no problem whatsoever.

```
{
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(checkNetworkStatus:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];

return YES;
}


- (void) checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice
{
// called after network status changes

NetworkStatus internetStatus = [internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
switch (internetStatus)

{
    case NotReachable:
    {
        NSLog(@"The internet is down.");
        internetConnectivity=@"NO";
        break;

    }
    case ReachableViaWiFi:
    {
        NSLog(@"The internet is working via WIFI.");
        internetConnectivity=@"YES";
        SyncRecords *obj=[[SyncRecords alloc]init];
        [obj syncData];
        break;

    }
    case ReachableViaWWAN:
    {
        NSLog(@"The internet is working via WWAN.");
        internetConnectivity=@"YES";
        SyncRecords *obj=[[SyncRecords alloc]init];
        [obj syncData];
        break;

    }
}

}
```